# facebook page posting not working properly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, facebook-page

Posting photos/videos in Facebook page from php application does not give any error but the post does not show up in page feed.

Same code used to work before the new facebook rules came.

**Following are the permission i have taken to post on page:**

***publish_actions,manage_pages***

*code used:*

```
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '{appid}';
    $config['secret'] = '{app secret}';

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    $facebook->setAccessToken({fb_token});
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $params = array(
                          'message'       =>  "{title}",
                          'name'          =>  "{name}",
                          'link'          =>  "{link}",
                          'picture'       =>  "{picture url}",

                      );
$facebook->api("{page-id}/feed","POST",$params);
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand.
I have one test account and i have created a page in that account.and i m trying to post on that page using the page id i get when i query
me/accounts

Comment: a test account? use a real account and a real page instead. and check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things may be the problem:

- You are trying with a user without a role in your App - for that, you will have to get those permissions approved by Facebook in the [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process.
- You are using an App Access Token, but a Page Access Token is what you need. Here are some articles about getting a Page Token and Access Tokens in general:

  - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  - http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
  - http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Also, use try-catch to check for any errors, and see if the API call responds:

```
try {
    $response = $facebook->api("{page-id}/feed","POST",$params);
    var_dump($response);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: posting has started but it is posted on behalf of user on the page.. i want it to look like it is posted by page itself.
Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: if it posts as user, you are using a user token, not a page token. make sure you are using a page token.